# Symfony doctrine result query wrong format

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine

I got a weird situation and I'm not sure how to fix it.

I got a query result in doctrine which the format looks strange.

I use doctrine to execute a query like the next example:

```
$query = "select ... from ..."
$stmt = $this->oracleDB->prepare($query); 
(This oracleDB is configured in the config.yml with "charset: ISO-8859-1" and "driver: oci8")
$stmt->bindValue(1, $variable, "...");
more binds...
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

The most part of times the results are normals and json_encode works but sometimes I get a result like the next one:

```
dump($results);
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▼
    "BLA1" => "xx"
    "BLA2" => "XX"
    "BLA3" => "XX"
    "BLA4" => "XX"
    "BLA5" => b"XX"
    "BLA6" => "XX"
  ]
]
var_dump($results);
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=12)
      'BLA1' => string 'XX' (length=2)
      'BLA2' => string 'XX' (length=2)
      'BLA3' => string 'XX' (length=2)
      'BLA4' => string 'XX' (length=2)
      'BLA5' => string 'X�X' (length=3)
      'BLA6' => string 'XX' (length=2)

dump(json_encode($results));
false
```

if I unset the BLA5 the json_encode works nice.

```
unset($result[0]['BLA5']);

dump($result);
array:1 [▼
0 => array:5 [▼
    "BLA1" => "xx"
    "BLA2" => "XX"
    "BLA3" => "XX"
    "BLA4" => "XX"
    "BLA6" => "XX"
  ]
]

dump(json_encode($results));
"[{"BLA1":"XX","BLA2":"XX","BLA3":"XX","BLA4":"XX","BLA6":"XX"}] ◀"
```

Any idea?

Comment: It could be due to `ISO-8859-1` encoding?

Comment: Yes... I was informed that it was supposed to be ISO-8859-1 but finally it wasn't. Is another charset. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was expecting to have the database with the charset ISO-8859-1 but actually wasn't. So all under control. Thx!